# How do I mount an external USB CD Drive in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, mount, usb-drive

I am about to get Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a netbook running windows 7 starter. It does not have a built-in CD-ROM, so I have an external Samsung CD-ROM. I am afraid it will not work with Ubuntu, unless I mount it. What is a good Linux command to mount my CD-ROM so it can work on my netbook when it gets Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to do anything special in windows, chances are you won't have to do anything special in Ubuntu. Both Operating Systems have `Plug and Play` functionality.

Basically just plug in the CD ROM USB drive (comments below speculate it is really CD/DVD optical drive) and see if it works. If it doesn't work, then update your question or post a new one.

There is no "good Linux command" to mount a CD, DVD or Blu-ray. When a disc is inserted you will be given the option to launch an application based on disc content. For typical data operations you will choose to use `Nautilus` (Ubuntu's file manager / explorer) to navigate the disc for files you want to access.

Comment: I believe OP is using `CD-ROM` to mean the actual optical drive. Most laptops don't have built in CDs (unless I've been ripped off or haven't found the compartment with my 700MB disc yet).

Comment: I'm sure you are right that it is a CD/DVD external USB drive and the OP made a typo or is speaking generically. Laptop internal CD-ROM drives went obsolete about the same time USB became common place I think. Therefore external Samsung CD-ROM (only) USB drives probably don't exist.

Comment: I'm stumped on the Apple comment... The only Apple product I own is a 4GB iPod generation 3 or something like that.... which I don't use anymore as Android smartphone with 64gb micro SD card and Bluetooth earbuds out classes it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46490/discussion-between-wineunuuchs2unix-and-zacharee1).